# What are these pieces for?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, sets, piece-usage

I got these pieces from set [76119 "Batmobile Pursuit of Joker"](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/batmobile-pursuit-of-the-joker-76119), but the instructions don't specify what the pieces are for. What is their purpose?

[image]

Comment: They're included because the model uses one of the bat pieces as part of the build, and if you include one of these pieces, you need to include all of them because they're packaged in a bag together

Answer (score 14):

According to the [official description](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/batmobile-pursuit-of-the-joker-76119), these are for customizing the completed build:

> This LEGO Batman toy playset includes 2 minifigures and children can customize their builds, minifigures and weapons with the included pack of 10 assorted Bat elements.